# How to ensure functional dependencies are used to unify dependent existential type variables

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

I have a typeclass that introduces a functional dependency between two types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Eq c => Classifiable t c | t -> c where 
    classification :: t -> c
```

I have a number of instances of this class, e.g. for pairs, we use that the "classification" of the pair is the value stored in the first position:

```
instance Eq a => Classifiable (a,b) a where
    classification = fst
```

I also have a type that uses this class to allow it to store an instance of type `c` when configured with type `t` in its arguemnts, i.e. `c` is existentially qualified, but it is constrained by the functional dependency to have exactly one actual possible type that is determined uniquely by one of the visible arguments, in this case `t`:

```
data Symbol t nt s where
    Terminal ::    (Classifiable t c, Show c, Ord c) =>
                   c                         -> Symbol t nt s
    NonTerminal :: Classifiable t c =>
                   nt -> [Production t nt s] -> Symbol t nt s
```

My problem is that when I try to use this, GHC is apparently unaware that for any pair of `Symbol`s with given arguments, the type `c` must be the same if `t` is.  Hence, if I try to create an instance of `Ord` for this type:

```
deriving instance (Ord c, Ord nt, Classifiable t c) =>   Ord (Symbol t nt s)
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Eq (Symbol t nt s))
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
from the context (Ord c, Ord nt, Classifiable t c)
  bound by the instance declaration
  at src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs:16:1-76
In the instance declaration for `Ord (Symbol t nt s)'
C:\development\haskell\delta-parser-git\delta-parser\src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs: 16, 1
Couldn't match expected type `c1' with actual type `c2'
  `c2' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         Terminal :: forall t nt s c.
                     (Classifiable t c, Show c, Ord c) =>
                     c -> Symbol t nt s,
       in a case alternative
       at src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs:16:1
  `c1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         Terminal :: forall t nt s c.
                     (Classifiable t c, Show c, Ord c) =>
                     c -> Symbol t nt s,
       in a case alternative
       at src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs:16:1
Relevant bindings include
  b1 :: c2 (bound at src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs:16:1)
  a1 :: c1 (bound at src\Text\Parser\ALLStar.hs:16:1)
In the second argument of `compare', namely `b1'
In the expression: (a1 `compare` b1)
When typechecking the code for  `compare'
  in a derived instance for `Ord (Symbol t nt s)':
  To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
```

How can I persuade the compiler to understand that the two `c` bindings are required to be the same type by the functional dependency?

Comment: I guess functional dependencies do not introduce `c1 ~ c2` constraints -- arguably, they should. I'd consider switching to type families instead of fundeps.

Comment: "How can I persuade the compiler to understand that the two c bindings are required to be the same type by the functional dependency?" - with `unsafeCoerce`. (You could also use associated types instead of fundeps.) I think I answered a question about this a while ago, but I can't find it now. But basically, the fact you hope to state isn't true; if it were, two different modules could have two different instances for the same type, e.g. `Classifiable Int Bool` and `Classifiable Int String`, and a third module importing both modules would be able to prove `Bool ~ String`.

Comment: @user2407038 could you please clarify why that's an issue, given that having access to both instances would lead to a compiler error? Isn't the same construction also possible with associated types?